# How to create more than one Shared-Preferences on Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I created 2 shared preferences files. But automatically remove the first file. How to create multiple shared preferences files in Flutter?

**First file**

```
Future<bool> saveUrlPreference(String token,String refreshToken) async {
  List<String> tokens = [token,refreshToken];
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  pref.setStringList('tokens', tokens);
  return pref.commit();
}
```

**Second file**

```
Future<bool> saveUrlPreference(String Url) async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  pref.setString("url", Url);
  return pref.commit();
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can do it at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not yet supported

Upvote and follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14337

Comment: okay. tell me your suggestion to store multiple values..sqlite?

Comment: You could use a prefix to differentiate until this feature becomes available.